# how to create socket between two android devices, Socket doesn't work on main thread and thus creating problems

Tags: android, performance, sockets, socket.io, android-developer-api

I have successfully established connection between two devices but to transfer data of files I have to create socket, and I have constantly failed to do so. After making errors I got to know that sockets work on different thread other then main thread. so I created threads but then I get null pointer exception means the value is vacant and I don't know how??
here's what I have tried form different source and tutorials.

```
     senddatatry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String msg=trytext.getText().toString();

            receivedata.write(msg);

        }
    });

  final WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener connectionInfoListener = new WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(final WifiP2pInfo info) {

        inetAddress = info.groupOwnerAddress;


        if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {

            deviceStatus.setText("Host");
            ServerClass serverClass = new ServerClass();
            serverClass.start();

        } else if (info.groupFormed) {


            deviceStatus.setText("Client");
            Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    super.run();
                    clientClass = new ClientClass(inetAddress);
                    clientClass.start();

                }
            };
            thread1.start();

        }

    }
};


   public class ServerClass extends Thread{

     Socket socket;
     ServerSocket serverSocket;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        try {
            serverSocket=new ServerSocket(8888);
            socket=serverSocket.accept();
            InputStream input=socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            final String msg=reader.readLine();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    deviceStatus.setText(msg);

                }
            });
            Log.d("server","test");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}

public class ClientClass extends Thread{

    Socket socket;
    OutputStream outputStream;
    final String hstname;
    public ClientClass(InetAddress address)
    {
        this.hstname=address.getHostName();


    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        if(hstname!=null){
            try {
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hstname,8888),1000);
                outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();
                receivedata=new receivedata(outputStream);
                receivedata.start();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }



    }




}

public class receivedata extends Thread{
    OutputStream outputStream;
    public receivedata (OutputStream stream){
        this.outputStream=stream;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        Log.d("start","thread working");

    }

    public void write(String msg){

        PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter(outputStream,true);
        writer.println(msg);

    }

}
```

I have added button on clicklistner from where string is received and I have added server class, client class and where they have been initialized
I have gone through all possible way I knew but I failed.
Please anyone suggest me how can successfully create socket to transfer data. please It's a humble request, I tried but I don't know. So if you could suggest or help me with this, it would be a great favor

Comment: I have done the modification as per requirement, so now please do suggest something.

Comment: Which line gives a null pointer exception? Please post the relevant lines from the logcat .

Comment: `receivedata.write(msg);` No. You cannot just call a public member of a thread class to execute internet code. All internet code should be put in the run() of your thread.

Comment: so you mean to say that i can just collect message via write method and to send data i have to use outputStream and PrintWriter method  in run method of thread. is this what you mean to say?? really thank you for your kind help

Comment: and also can you suggest some source or link from where I can get deep information related to this...

Comment: Repeat: all code concerning your socket, be it connecting, reading, writing, closing should be executed in the run of a thread. For every action you can use a different thread.

Comment: `i can just collect message via write method ` Typo? You would use a read merhod for that.