# Send text file from Android(Android Studio) to PC via Wi-Fi(Socket)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making a project for the exam.
I wanna make a smart greenhouse. The sensors and arduino will control it.

HC-05 will send data about temperature, humidity and light inside the greenhouse to my phone when I walk close to it, after that I should send data from my phone to my PC using LAN.

This is the point I get stuck on:

I have read the doc about Socket, yet. App kept throwing NetworkOnMainThreadException, I read a lots of others question similar to this on SO, nothing worked!
I understood that this exception is thrown when I try to instance a socket in main thread: it halts UI. I I tried to use an handler with a runnable, seems like it hasn't been run!

I have read about AsyncTask, but that's deprecated.
Could someone help me to get this achieve(Send text file to the PC via Android)?

Comment: `HC-05 will send data about temperature, humidity and light inside the greenhouse to my phone` And why isnt there a NetworkOnMainThreadException when the phone receives that info?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65990636/how-to-create-socket-between-two-android-devices-socket-doesnt-work-on-main-th?noredirect=1#comment116682209_65990636

Comment: I haven't still bought hc05. The exception is thrown when I try to connect my phone's socket to the PC. So now I need to know how to transfer file from my phone to the PC

Comment: No. You should google for NetworkOnMainThreadException. And all needed is in the link i gave you.